# Selecting objects in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose 36 objects are placed along a circle at equal distances. In how many ways can 3 objects be chosen
from among them so that no two of the three chosen objects are adjacent nor diametrically opposite?

Answer (score 1):

Total ways of 3 selections = ${C_{3}}^{36}$

Three at adjacent positions = $36$

Exactly two at consecutive positions = $36 * 32$

Diametrically opposite but not adjacent = $\frac{36 * 30}{2}$

So ${C_{3}}^{36} – 36 – 36*32 – 18*30
= 5412$